# MATLAB: Calling .m files in a loop

Tags: loops, matlab

How do I call 3 MATLAB **.m** files in a loop and display the results in sequence?

Answer (score 5):

Another option (in addition to [Amro's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658290/matlab-plotting-m-file-from-directory/1658316#1658316)) is to use [function handles](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-38133.html):

```
fileList = {@file1 @file2 @file3};  % A cell array of function handles
for iFile = 1:numel(fileList)
  fileList{iFile}();                % Evaluate the function handle
  pause                             % Wait for a keypress to continue
end
```

You can [call a function using its handle](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-38133.html#brfp2ju-1) as I did above or using the function [FEVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/feval.html). If you have a function name in a string, you can use the function [STR2FUNC](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/str2func.html) to convert it to a function handle (assuming it isn't a [nested function](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-39683.html), which requires the function handle constructor `@`). The following example illustrates each of these alternatives:

```
fileList = {str2func('file1') str2func('file2') str2func('file3')};
for iFile = 1:numel(fileList)
  feval(fileList{iFile});           % Evaluate the function handle
  pause                             % Wait for a keypress to continue
end
```

---

### How do the two answers differ?

You may be wondering what the difference is between my answer (using function handles) and [Amro's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658290/matlab-plotting-m-file-from-directory/1658316#1658316) (using strings). For very simple cases, you would likely see no difference. However, you can run into more complicated [scoping and function precedence issues](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f7-58170.html#bresuvu-3) if you use strings for the function names and evaluate them with [EVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html). Here's an example to illustrate...

Let's say we have two m-files:

*fcnA.m*

```
function fcnA
  disp('I am an m-file!');
end
```

*fcnB.m*

```
function fcnB(inFcn)
  switch class(inFcn)       % Check the data type of inFcn...
    case 'char'             % ...and do this if it is a string...
      eval(inFcn);
    case 'function_handle'  % ...or this if it is a function handle
      inFcn();
  end
end
function fcnA                   % A subfunction in fcnB.m
  disp('I am a subfunction!');
end
```

The function `fcnB` is designed to take either a function name or a function handle and evaluate it. By an unfortunate coincidence (or maybe intentionally) there is a subfunction in *fcnB.m* that is also called `fcnA`. What happens when we call `fcnB` in two different ways?

```
>> fcnB('fcnA')      % Pass a string with the function name
I am a subfunction!
>> fcnB(@fcnA)       % Pass a function handle
I am an m-file!
```

Notice that passing the function name as a string causes the subfunction `fcnA` to be evaluated. This is because at the time that EVAL is called the subfunction `fcnA` has the highest [function precedence](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f7-58170.html#bresuvu-6) of all the functions named `fcnA`. In contrast, passing a function handle causes the m-file `fcnA` to be called instead. This is because the function handle is created *first*, then passed to `fcnB` as an argument. The m-file `fcnA` is the only one in scope (i.e. the only one that can be called) outside of `fcnB`, and is thus the one the function handle is tied to.

In general, I prefer to use function handles because I feel it gives me more control over which specific function is being called, thus avoiding unexpected behavior as in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your files are [scripts](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/scripts.html) containing the plotting commands, you can do the following:

```
mfiles = {'file1' 'file2' 'file3'};
for i=1:length(mfiles)
    eval( mfiles{i} );
    pause
end
```

where for example, we have:

*file1.m*

```
x = 0:0.1:2*pi;
plot(x, sin(x))
```